# Add custom php function to xpath using goutte

Tags: php, xpath, goutte

i wanted to know if it possible to add custom php function my xpath query using goutte, i've saw that there is a function named: registerPHPFunctions in DOMXpath but i cant find it when i use goutte. so is it possible using this library? Thanks